# Why is redirecting script's output to a file giving an incorrect output?

Tags: python, shell, redirect

This is the python script `sum_columns.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import sys

num_nodes = 0
num_edges = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
   line = line.strip()
   col_1, col_2 = line.split(',', 1)

   col_1 = int(col_1)
   col_2 = int(col_2)

   num_nodes += col_1
   num_edges += col_2

print '%s, %s' % (num_nodes, num_edges)
```

There's a file called `outputs.dat` with 1 line:

```
10, 10
```

I am trying to redirect the output of the python script into the input file `outputs.dat`, but when I do this, it writes out `0, 0`, when I am expecting `10, 10`. When I redirect to another file not named `outputs.dat` I get `10, 10`. Why is this happening?

Here are the commands I am executing.

```
[local_serv]$ cat outputs.dat
10, 10
[local_serv]$ cat outputs.dat | ./sum_columns.py 
10, 10
[local_serv]$ cat outputs.dat | ./sum_columns.py > test.dat; cat test.dat
10, 10
[local_serv]$ cat outputs.dat | ./sum_columns.py > outputs.dat; cat outputs.dat
0, 0
[local_serv]$
```

My understanding is that `>` rewrites `outputs.dat` (if it already exists), why would it rewrite it as `0, 0` when the python script prints `10, 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that `>` rewrites `outputs.dat` (if it already exists),

Yes, exactly, it truncates the file.

> why would it rewrite it as `0, 0` when the python script prints `10, 10`?

It doesn't print that. The Python script *reads* the contents of the file to perform some calculations based on its contents, but `>` *truncates* the file, so when Python reads its contents, it is empty.

Comment: It seems that I missed the order of operations here. Are you saying the python script is executed after the `>` is executed?

Comment: Yes. `>` means that the script is started with its standard output stream connected to `outputs.dat`. Before that, the file will be truncated.

Comment: ahh I wasn't aware of that. I thought the order of operations in linux terminal is always from left to right.

Comment: How can the output of the script end up in the file if the file is not connected to the output *before* the script is started? What if the script prints something as the very first thing it does? What if the script tests whether the standard output is a file or a terminal and then does different things based on that? The only possible way how this can work is if the standard output gets redirected *before* the command is started.

Comment: OHH. I totally missed that. In the Python script, I put the print command at the very end of the program, so I was thinking it the shell would open the output file for writing when it sees the first print command.